# desciption text after hovering a profile picture

Tags: jquery, html, css

I want to display a text after hovering a profile picture. I have made a 'title 'tag but it cannot show the text in different paragraphs. Are there alternative ways to do this?

Here is my CSS code:

```
.tooltip {
   display:none;
   position:absolute;
   border:1px solid #333;
   background-color:#161616;
   border-radius:5px;
   padding:10px;
   color:#fff;
   font-size:12px Arial;
}
```

Here is my html code:

```
<table style="width:100%">
<tr>
<td><a><img src="http://2017.igem.org/wiki/images/2/26/Andrew.PNG" width="200" height="200" class="masterTooltip" title="Name: Ching Yuet To; Major/Year: Cell and Molecular Biology/3 "></a></td>
<td><img src="http://2017.igem.org/wiki/images/d/de/Venus.PNG" width="200" height="200"></td>
<td><img src="http://2017.igem.org/wiki/images/8/84/Cathy.PNG" width="200" height="200"></td>
</tr>
</table>

<script>
$(function () {
  $(document).tooltip({
      content: function () {
          return $(this).prop('title');
      }
  });
});
</script>
```

Comment: provide a working fiddle

Comment: have you included jquery-ui  js and css?

Comment: @Hornet I have included Js, css but not jquery.......

Comment: @Redo I don't know how to use fiddle

Comment: check your console tab, there must be errors,

Comment: there is a button `<>` in the textarea. Use it and add required resource links. You're done

Comment: Do you need to use tables? or Do you need the functionality?

Comment: @ Muhammad Akber Khan Would you mind to tell me in detail..... sorry that I don't  get what you mean

Comment: on hover the text is shown?

Comment: @hunzaboy Yes I want to display those images inside a table...... Functionality you mean hover the image to show a tooltip with text ? If yes, I think I need it

Comment: @hash Yes, the text is shown but just in a continuous sentence format. I want to separate the points by open a new paragraph

Comment: @AlanChiu what is your mean of paragraph?

Comment: you have to add <br> in title attribute.
<img src="http://2017.igem.org/wiki/images/2/26/Andrew.PNG" width="200" height="200" class="masterTooltip" title="Name: Ching Yuet To;<br> Major/Year: Cell and Molecular Biology/3 "/>

Comment: @ehsan  Open a new line to show a new point..... not all points group into 1 sentence

Comment: @ashup. I have tried it....but it didn't work.....the <br> also appear in the sentence :(

Comment: add this argument in img tag data-html="true"
it should work

Comment: @ashu p. would you mind to show me in detail? Many thanks :)

Comment: @AlanChiu https://jsfiddle.net/g3fue676/

Comment: @ashu p. But if I foolow your suggestion before: I input another sentence to 'title' then add a <br> between, <br> also showed in tooltip and still grouping into 1 sentence rather than separate to new line

Answer (score 0):

This is an alternate way of doing it. Just a few changes to your original code. Hope this helps.

```css
a {
  position: relative;
}
a:after {
  position: absolute;
  display: none;
  content: attr(data-tooltip);
  bottom: 0;
  border: 1px solid #333;
  background-color: #161616;
  border-radius: 5px;
  padding: 10px;
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 12px Arial;
}
a:hover:after {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<table style="width:100%">
<tr>
<td><a data-tooltip="Name: Ching Yuet To; Major/Year: Cell and Molecular Biology/3"><img src="http://2017.igem.org/wiki/images/2/26/Andrew.PNG" width="200" height="200" class="masterTooltip"></a></td>
  <td><a data-tooltip="Tooltip"><img src="http://2017.igem.org/wiki/images/d/de/Venus.PNG" width="200" height="200"></a></td>
  <td><a data-tooltip="Tooltip"><img src="http://2017.igem.org/wiki/images/8/84/Cathy.PNG" width="200" height="200"></a></td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Comment: This is wrong,because if width text in first line be less, all text get in one line.for example: if `Name: Ching Yuet To;` br `Name: Ching;`

Comment: @ehsan, Its just a tooltip. And from my understanding from the question i think this help him out. If you have any more ideas please feel free to answer.

Comment: `Name:` and `Major/Year:` must be in two different line.in your answer if width `Name:...` be less than width container , so part of  `Major/Year:` come to same line.

Comment: @ehsan , oh ok got it :)

Answer (score 0):

You can put line breaks in your actual HTML to separate the content of your title text onto separate lines by pressing enter, like this:

```
<table style="width:100%">
<tr>
<td><a><img src="http://2017.igem.org/wiki/images/2/26/Andrew.PNG" width="200" height="200" class="masterTooltip" title="Name: Ching Yuet To;

Major/Year: Cell and Molecular Biology/3 "></a></td>
```

Or, use the line break character like this:

```
title="First paragraph&#10;&#10;Second paragraph
```

Fiddle:

https://jsfiddle.net/uukaw084/1/

Comment: @ehsan: Why are you making random edits on other people's posts?

Answer (score 0):

Alternative to jqueryUI tooltip is just define your own simple plugin for tooltip so that it can be customised as per your requirements.

This simple tooltip plugin displays tooltip relative to mouse position.

```js
let tooltips = $('.tooltip span');

(function($) {
  $.fn.mytooltip = function(e) {
    let x = (e.pageX + 20) + 'px',
      y = (e.pageY + 20) + 'px';

    for (let i = 0; i < tooltips.length; i++) {
      tooltips[i].style.top = y;
      tooltips[i].style.left = x;
    }
    return this;
  };
}(jQuery));

$('a').on('mousemove', function(e) {
  $(this).mytooltip(e);
});
```

```css
.tooltip {
  text-decoration: none;
  position: relative;
}

.tooltip span {
  display: none;
}

.tooltip:hover span {
  display: block;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, .8);
  color: #fff;
  border-radius: 5px;
  padding: 5px 15px;
  position: fixed;
  overflow: hidden;
  z-index: 99;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<a class="tooltip">
  <img alt="" src="http://2017.igem.org/wiki/images/2/26/Andrew.PNG" width="200" height="200" />
  <span>hiiiiii</span>
</a>
<a class="tooltip">
  <img alt="" src="http://2017.igem.org/wiki/images/d/de/Venus.PNG" width="200" height="200" />
  <span>hello</span>
</a>
```

Hope.. this alternative solution works for you.!!

Answer (score 0):

You Must help of jquery.Like This:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('img').on('mousemove',function(e){
        var txt ="";
       var x = $(this).attr('data').split(';');
       $.each(x, function( index, value ) {
         txt += value + "<br>";
     })
       $('.myTooltip').css({'left':e.clientX + 10,'top':e.clientY})
       $('.myTooltip').html(txt).show();
    })

    $('img').on('mouseleave',function(){
        $('.myTooltip').hide();
    }) 

})
```

```css
.myTooltip {
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.8);
    color: orange;
    display: inline-block;
    position: absolute;
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table style="width:100%">
    <tr>
        <td>
            <a>
                <img src="http://2017.igem.org/wiki/images/2/26/Andrew.PNG" width="200" height="200" class="masterTooltip" data="Name: Ching Yuet To; Major/Year: Cell and Molecular Biology/3 ">
            </a>
        </td>
        <td>
            <a>
                <img data="Name: Maryam; Major/Year:Geneticist/40" src="http://2017.igem.org/wiki/images/d/de/Venus.PNG" width="200" height="200">
            </a>
        </td>

        <td>
            <a>
                <img data="Name: Shila Amir; Major/Year:Laboratory sciences / 29 " src="http://2017.igem.org/wiki/images/8/84/Cathy.PNG" width="200" height="200">
            </a>    
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
<span class="myTooltip"></span>
```